# Can I apply master theorem to this problem?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I have a problem

$ T(n) = 7T(\sqrt[3]{n}+5)+n\log_3{n} $

Can I solve this by applying master theorem? I'm confused, because this equation does not resemble master's theorem generic form or should algebraically change this equation to resemble it?

If not, what are the other ways in solving the problem? Can I also use recursion tree?

Comment: Why not go back to simple tools? If every $T(n)$ is nonnegative, then obviously $T(n)\geqslant n\log_3n$. In the other direction, can you prove recursively that $T(n)\leqslant cn\log_3n$ for every $n$, if $c$ is large enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you exchange the values of place it seems that yes (If you change the ones between an asterisk):
$$T(n) = 7T(**\sqrt[3]{n}+5**)+**n\log_3{n}**$$
but just like that, it seems that not.

The algorithm you are referring to has recursive design ... so if you are able to leave that expression in such a way that it can be applied, also by extension you can do it with a recursion tree.

The first 7 pages of [this pdf](http://marenas.sitios.ing.uc.cl/iic2283-16/clases/analisis-II-imp.pdf) can help you manipulate your expression, to see if you get it.

As a curiosity and for you to locate in computer science (if you are interested) are generically called voracious algorithms and what you refer to specifically as "master" has a curious and somewhat philosophical name (I think) that is "Divide and conquer".